# How to make OTP login with retrofit2 with java in mvvm design pattern?

Tags: java, android, api, mvvm, retrofit2

I have a field for a phone number on one page and OTP verification on another Activity.
I have to make an API call in my app using Retrofit2. I am new to API integration.

Comment: Are you expecting whole logic or only network call!?

Comment: @GobuCSG I want to know how that whole logic gets implemented using MVVM.

Comment: First try to implement MVVM pattern then implement your OTP logics.. collect mobile num from input send it to server then show verify OTP UI. SAMPLE: https://www.google.com/amp/s/c1ctech.com/android-mvvm-pattern-with-retrofit-in-kotlin/amp/

Comment: Don't post this kind of ques... Post your problems and challenges..

Comment: @GobuCSG How to make companion objects in the java. I have stuck with that.

Comment: You can't see... It's kotlin... You've to create static method.. whatever declared inside companion object those fields, methods are static..